# How to use Composer to update just the Magento 2 core packages?

Tags: magento2, composer, core, package

I would like to use the composer update feature to update all the core packages, **not the third-party packages** together.

Do you have some idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one command to update a **Magento Opensource** or **Magento Commerce** version.

```
composer update vendor/magento
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via these commands below.

Magento Opensource:

```
composer update magento/product-community-edition
```

Magento Commerce:

```
composer update magento/product-enterprise-edition
```

This will only update Magento package.